# Performs tuning on "Not Exists" and "Exists"

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA RS1
INNER JOIN TableB TB
   on  TB.headkey =Rs1.headerkey
INNER JOIN TableC TC
     on  TC.headkey =Rs1.headerkey
.....
.....  {Several Inner joins on different tables}
.....
WHERE 
    "RS1"."SQTY" > 0 AND
    "RS1"."PP_KEY" = '123' AND
    TRIM(BOTH FROM "RS1"."CTOLK") IS NULL AND
    NOT ( EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        "tableaA" "RS2" 
    WHERE 
        "RS2"."SQTY" > 0 AND
        "RS2"."STAT" < '33800' AND
        "RS2"."headerkey" = "RS1"."headerkey"
    ) ) AND
    EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        "tableaA" "RS2" 
    WHERE 
        "RS2"."SQTY" > 0 AND
        "RS2"."STaT" = '33800.100' AND
        "RS2"."SDATE" BETWEEN TRUNC(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)) - 7 AND TRUNC(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)) AND
        "RS2"."headerkey" = "RS1"."headerkey"
    )
```

Is there any efficient way of writing the "WHERE Clause" as the "tableA" has more than 250 million records and its been repeated more than twice in the where clause causing huge time of execution

Comment: Quick question: Why `TRUNC(TRUNC(SYSDATE))`? How is that different from just `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`?

Comment: The double-quoted identifiers are confusing. Do you really have two separate tables named `TABLEA` and `"tableA"`, and do they have separate columns `HEADERKEY` and `"headerkey"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analytic functions were introduced pretty much for this purpose... avoid having to read the same table more than once. You need two conditional analytic counts - as `tableA` is being read (not all of it, just the rows with `"SQTY" > 0`, if that makes a difference), the rows are partitioned by `headerkey` and the two needed conditional counts are calculated. Then you can filter the result of reading the rows (and adding the analytic functions), replacing the `WHERE` clause.

Something like this: (using the `WITH` clause, which makes code more readable)

```
WITH
  PREP as (
    SELECT *,
           count(case when "STAT" < '33800' then 1 end) 
                                  over (partition by headerkey) as ct1,
           count(case when "STAT" = '33800.100' 
                       and "SDATE" between trunc(sysdate) - 7 and trunc(sysdate)
                      then 1 end) over (partition by headerkey) as ct2
    FROM   tableA
    where  "SQTY" > 0
  ),
  RS2 as (
    SELECT * -- or just the columns you need
    FROM   PREP
    WHERE  "PP_KEY" = '123'
      AND  TRIM(BOTH FROM "CTOLK") IS NULL
      AND  ct1 = 0
      and  ct2 > 0
  )

SELECT * 
FROM  RS1
INNER JOIN TableB TB
   on  TB.headkey =Rs1.headerkey
INNER JOIN TableC TC
     on  TC.headkey =Rs1.headerkey
.....
.....  {Several Inner joins on different tables}
.....
WHERE 
   .......
```